# Windows Socket (UDP) - Client TIMEOUT issue

Tags: c, windows, sockets, udp, timeout

I've a server and a client (code posted bellow).
Im testing the **setsockopt** function with the **SO_RCVTIMEO** timeout option in the client program, and it seems to be compiling fine.
The procedure is: server binds to socket for reading - client sends a message to it - server shows message and resends it to whichever client sent it - and finally, client shows message recieved from server 
So, to check if the timeout actually fails after X amount of miliseconds (timeout is only used when the client is waiting for the message to be sent back from the server), i inserted a Sleep(miliseconds) function in the server just before it resends the message to the client, so as to balance this delay between the client and the server. 
So, when testing with Sleep(0) and timeout at 0 aswell, everything works perfectly synchronized, but if i lift the values to, say, 10 ms on both ends, the result should be the same as with 0, but actually, everything works as planned except when the client awaits for the server's response, it timeout's, eventhough the delay on both ends is exactly the same. 
As a last example: if the Sleep on the server is 10ms, and the timeout on the client is 11, or even 15 to leave some more room, what happens is, server recieves message, waits 10ms, resends it, the client that was suposed to wait another 5ms to complete the 15ms, actually timeout's. Even worse, the server after completeting it's whole process resumes it's initial awaiting-response loop, somehow gives me an error on the recvfrom. 
Excuse the huge text but it'd be really hard to summarize all of this without leaving some crutial details out.

Client.c (ignore the broadcast, it's not being used)

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SERV_HOST_ADDR "127.0.0.1"
#define SERV_UDP_PORT  6000

#define PORT_MAX 7000
#define PORT_MIN 1000

#define NUM_IT  10

#define BUFFERSIZE     4096

void Abort(char *msg);

/*________________________________ main _______________________________________
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    SOCKET sockfd;
    int msg_len, iResult, nbytes, addrlength, local_port;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, local;
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    WSADATA wsaData;
    //broadcast
    int broadcast, broadcast_loop;
    //timeout
    DWORD timeout;// = TIMEOUT;

    /*========================= TESTA A SINTAXE =========================*/

    if (argc != 9){
        fprintf(stderr, "(%d argumentos) Sintaxe: %s -msg \"msg\" -ip ip -port port -timeout microsegundos\n (ordem arbitraria)\n", argc, argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //tratar os argumentos//
    int pos_msg, pos_port, pos_ip, pos_timeout, i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-msg") == 0)
            pos_msg = i + 1;
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-ip") == 0)
            pos_ip = i + 1;
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-port") == 0)
            pos_port = i + 1;
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-timeout") == 0)
            pos_timeout = i + 1;
    }

    timeout = atol((char*)(LPCTSTR)argv[pos_timeout]); //converter timeout STRING para DWORD

    if (strcmp(argv[pos_ip], "255.255.255.255") == 0)
    {
        broadcast_loop = 1;
        broadcast = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        broadcast_loop = 0;
        broadcast = 0;
    }

    /*=============== INICIA OS WINSOCKS ==============*/

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    /*=============== CRIA SOCKET PARA ENVIO/RECEPCAO DE DATAGRAMAS ==============*/

    sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
        Abort("Impossibilidade de criar socket");

    /*================ CONFIGURA O SOCKET PARA TIMEOUT DE RECEPCAO ==============*/

    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));

    //this call is what allows broadcast packets to be sent:
    if (broadcast_loop == 1)
    {
        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char *)&broadcast, sizeof broadcast) == -1)
        {
            perror("setsockopt (SO_BROADCAST)");
            exit(1);
        }
    }


    /*================= PREENCHE ENDERECO DO SERVIDOR ====================*/

    memset((char*)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr)); /*Coloca a zero todos os bytes*/
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /*Address Family: Internet*/
    //serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERV_HOST_ADDR); /*IP no formato "dotted decimal" => 32 bits*/
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[pos_ip]);
    //serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERV_UDP_PORT); /*Host TO Netowork Short*/
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[pos_port]));

    /*====================== ENVIA MENSAGEM AO SERVIDOR ==================*/

    msg_len = strlen(argv[pos_msg]);

    if (broadcast_loop == 1)
    {
        //loop sem esperar pelo reenvio
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IT; i++)
        {
            for (int pt = PORT_MIN; pt <= PORT_MAX; pt++)
            {
                serv_addr.sin_port = htons(pt);
                if (sendto(sockfd, argv[pos_msg], msg_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    Abort("SO nao conseguiu aceitar o datagram");
                printf(" -Enviada mensagem %d (port: %d)\n", i, pt);

                //ir buscar a porta gerada automaticamente pare este socket e mostrá-la
                addrlength = sizeof(local);
                if (getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&local, &addrlength) == 0 && local.sin_family == AF_INET && addrlength == sizeof(local))
                {
                    local_port = ntohs(local.sin_port);
                }

                printf("<CLI1>Mensagem enviada (port: %d) ... aguardando pelo seu reenvio.\n", local_port);
            }

            //////// ESPERAR QUE MESMA MENSAGEM SEJA REENVIADA PELO SERVIDOR //////
            ////nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, NULL, NULL);
            ////memset((char*)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
            //addrlength = sizeof(serv_addr);
            //nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, &addrlength);

            //if (nbytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
            //  Abort("Erro na recepcao da mensagem");

            //buffer[nbytes] = '\0'; /*Termina a cadeia de caracteres recebidos com '\0'*/

            //printf("\n<CLI1>Mensagem recebida {%s}\n", buffer);

            //if (strcmp(inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr), SERV_HOST_ADDR) == 0 && ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port) == SERV_UDP_PORT)
            //  printf(" -Mensagem enviada pelo servidor -> %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port));
            //else
            //  printf(" -Mensagem NAO enviada pelo servidor -> %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port));

        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (sendto(sockfd, argv[pos_msg], msg_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            Abort("SO nao conseguiu aceitar o datagram");

        //ir buscar a porta gerada automaticamente pare este socket e mostrá-la
        addrlength = sizeof(local);
        if (getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&local, &addrlength) == 0 && local.sin_family == AF_INET && addrlength == sizeof(local))
        {
            local_port = ntohs(local.sin_port);
        }

        printf("<CLI1>Mensagem enviada (port: %d) ... aguardando pelo seu reenvio (timeout).\n", local_port);

        ////// ESPERAR QUE MESMA MENSAGEM SEJA REENVIADA PELO SERVIDOR //////
        //nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, NULL, NULL);
        //memset((char*)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
        addrlength = sizeof(serv_addr);
        nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, &addrlength);

        if (nbytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
        if (WSAGetLastError() != WSAETIMEDOUT)
            Abort("Erro na recepcao da mensagem");
        else
            Abort("Timeout de recepcao");


        buffer[nbytes] = '\0'; /*Termina a cadeia de caracteres recebidos com '\0'*/

        printf("\n<CLI1>Mensagem recebida {%s}\n", buffer);

        if (strcmp(inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr), SERV_HOST_ADDR) == 0 && ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port) == SERV_UDP_PORT)
            printf(" -Mensagem enviada pelo servidor -> %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port));
        else
            printf(" -Mensagem NAO enviada pelo servidor -> %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port));

    }

    /*========================= FECHA O SOCKET ===========================*/

    closesocket(sockfd);

    printf("\n");
    system("Pause");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/*________________________________ Abort________________________________________
Mostra uma mensagem de erro e o código associado ao ultimo erro com Winsocks.
Termina a aplicacao com "exit status" a 1 (constante EXIT_FAILURE)
________________________________________________________________________________*/

void Abort(char *msg)
{

    fprintf(stderr, "<CLI1>Erro fatal: <%s> (%d)\n", msg, WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

and Server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <Windows.h> //Sleep()

#define SERV_UDP_PORT 6000
#define BUFFERSIZE     4096

void Abort(char *msg);

/*________________________________ main ________________________________________
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SOCKET sockfd;
    int iResult, nbytes, msg_len, len;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    WSADATA wsaData;

    /*========================= TESTA A SINTAXE =========================*/

    if (argc != 5){
        fprintf(stderr, "(%d argumentos) Sintaxe: %s -port port -delay delay\n", argc, argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //tratar os argumentos//
    int pos_port, pos_delay, i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-port") == 0)
            pos_port = i + 1;
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-delay") == 0)
            pos_delay = i + 1;
    }

    /*=============== INICIA OS WINSOCKS ==============*/

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        getchar();
        exit(1);
    }

    /*============ CRIA O SOCKET PARA RECEPCAO/ENVIO DE DATAGRAMAS UDP ============*/

    if ((sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        Abort("Impossibilidade de abrir socket");

    /*=============== ASSOCIA O SOCKET AO  ENDERECO DE ESCUTA ===============*/

    /*Define que pretende receber datagramas vindos de qualquer interface de
    rede, no porto pretendido*/

    memset((char*)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; /*Address Family: Internet*/
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  /*Host TO Network Long*/
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[pos_port]));  /*Host TO Network Short*/

    /*Associa o socket ao porto pretendido*/

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        Abort("Impossibilidade de registar-se para escuta");


    /*================ PASSA A ATENDER CLIENTES INTERACTIVAMENTE =============*/

    while (1){

        fprintf(stderr, "<SER1>Esperando datagram...\n");

        len = sizeof(cli_addr);
        //recieve from, tem agora de saber de quem recebeu, para reenviar
        nbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &len);

        if (nbytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
            Abort("Erro na recepcao de datagrams");

        buffer[nbytes] = '\0'; /*Termina a cadeia de caracteres recebidos com '\0'*/
        printf("<SER1>Mensagem recebida {%s} de %s:%d\n", buffer, inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(cli_addr.sin_port));

        ////// REENVIAR A MENSAGEM AO CLIENTE //////

        msg_len = strlen(buffer);
        Sleep(atoi(argv[pos_delay])); //sleep de 'delay' milisegundos
        if (sendto(sockfd, buffer, msg_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, sizeof(cli_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            Abort("SO nao conseguiu aceitar o datagram");

        printf("<SER1>Mensagem reenviada.\n\n");

    }
    system("Pause");
}

/*________________________________ Abort________________________________________
Mostra uma mensagem de erro e o código associado ao ultimo erro com Winsocks.
Termina a aplicacao com "exit status" a 1 (constante EXIT_FAILURE)
________________________________________________________________________________*/

void Abort(char *msg)
{

    fprintf(stderr, "<SER1>Erro fatal: <%s> (%d)\n", msg, WSAGetLastError());
    printf("\n");
    system("Pause");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

If anyone could make sense out of all this post and provide some helpful answers, i'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Try some higher timeouts: ping times between client and server can easily reach 4ms or higher already, so 5ms is cutting it very close.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i forgot to explain this is done within the same pc (ip -> 127.0.0.1)
It's just a bit of testing between some exercises for a college class.
Edit : When i ping 127.0.0.1 it gives me 1ms of time